# How to Create a Data Pool in Jasmin?

Tags: java, constants, pool, jasmin

Does Jasmin have the ability to specify a constant pool? I need to be able to create a descriptor area of thousands of bytes. The area will contain arbitrary byte data including nulls. Here's an example of a typical assembly directive to declare binary constants:

```
data  0x00, 0x01, 10, 32 ...
```

Seems that Java class files contain these areas but I can't find a way in Jasmin to declare the values on such a large scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That area in the Java class file is called the Constant Pool and is described in detail in [§4.4 of the JVM Spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#20080).

It can't, however contain arbitrary untyped data, but instead contains typed data **only**.

Supported data types are:

- `CONSTANT_Class`
- `CONSTANT_Fieldref`
- `CONSTANT_Methodref`
- `CONSTANT_InterfaceMethodref`
- `CONSTANT_String`
- `CONSTANT_Integer`
- `CONSTANT_Float`
- `CONSTANT_Long`
- `CONSTANT_Double`
- `CONSTANT_NameAndType`
- `CONSTANT_Utf8`

**None** of those types support arbitrary `byte` data of arbitrary length. [`CONSTANT_Utf8`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#7963) comes closest, but requires its content to be valid UTF-8 data and doesn't allow 0 bytes.

The best way to find out how `byte[]` are encoded is to define one in Java and decompile the resulting `.class` file. <strike>As far as I know</strike> A `byte[]` is compiled to an initializer block setting its fields.

Confirmed: This Java class:

```
public class Test {
  byte[] b = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 100 };
}
```

Decompiles to this (using `javac Test.java && javap -v Test`):

```
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test extends java.lang.Object
  SourceFile: "Test.java"
  minor version: 0
  major version: 50
  Constant pool:
const #1 = Method   #4.#13; //  java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
const #2 = Field    #3.#14; //  Test.b:[B
const #3 = class    #15;    //  Test
const #4 = class    #16;    //  java/lang/Object
const #5 = Asciz    b;
const #6 = Asciz    [B;
const #7 = Asciz    <init>;
const #8 = Asciz    ()V;
const #9 = Asciz    Code;
const #10 = Asciz   LineNumberTable;
const #11 = Asciz   SourceFile;
const #12 = Asciz   Test.java;
const #13 = NameAndType #7:#8;//  "<init>":()V
const #14 = NameAndType #5:#6;//  b:[B
const #15 = Asciz   Test;
const #16 = Asciz   java/lang/Object;

{
byte[] b;

public Test();
  Code:
   Stack=5, Locals=1, Args_size=1
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   aload_0
   5:   iconst_5
   6:   newarray byte
   8:   dup
   9:   iconst_0
   10:  iconst_0
   11:  bastore
   12:  dup
   13:  iconst_1
   14:  iconst_1
   15:  bastore
   16:  dup
   17:  iconst_2
   18:  iconst_2
   19:  bastore
   20:  dup
   21:  iconst_3
   22:  iconst_3
   23:  bastore
   24:  dup
   25:  iconst_4
   26:  bipush  100
   28:  bastore
   29:  putfield    #2; //Field b:[B
   32:  return
  LineNumberTable: 
   line 1: 0
   line 2: 4


}
```

As you can see, the generated constructor "manually" sets the 5 values into the newly allocated array.

Comment: Interesting information but it doesn't address the question. How can this be done in Jasmin?

Comment: Since the Java `class` file format doesn't support storing arbitrary `byte[]`, it **can't be done** in Jasmin. The only thing you can do in Jasmin is the same thing: generate code that populates a `byte[]`.

Comment: ok, let's simplify the request. How can I specify Asciz in Jasmin? I have verified that I can use the ldc opcode with an operand of at least 60,000 character quoted string. I'd prefer to do that in a data declaration statement. Is that possible?

Comment: @BSalita: checking the Jasmin homepage it looks like you can't define the constant pool entry explicitly. You can only do so indirectly via a `ldc` (which will put its argument into the constant pool).

Comment: Thanks, I believe that's the answer too. Seems like a serious omission in jasmin. While serious, it only effects a minority of users. ldc is an ok workaround. Thanks for all your follow throughs. I'll mark your response as the answer.